# DataGridView Exception thrown during InitializeComponent

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, datagridview

This is only occurring on a user's machine, not mine. I cannot recreate this issue. Since this is occurring inside the DataGridView's internal code, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.get_Item(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
   at BatchTransactionTool.TransactionPreview.grdTransaction_CellValueChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueChangedInternal(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.set_HeaderText(String value)
   at BatchTransactionTool.TransactionPreview.InitializeComponent()
   at BatchTransactionTool.TransactionPreview..ctor(FileInfo AutoSaveFile, BatchTransactionSummary bts, cbTeam team, List`1 transactionList, List`1 reinvestSecurities, Nullable`1 type, TransactionUnitType unit)
   at BatchTransactionTool.TransactionPreview..ctor(cbTeam team, List`1 transactionList, List`1 reinvstSecurities, TransactionType type, TransactionUnitType unit)
   at BatchTransactionTool.BatchTransactionTool.btnDisplayResults_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the .net framework. Updating to the latest service packs fixed the issue.